# Excel, complication IF/ELSE/MACROS

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am totally stuck on this one, your assistance will be greatly valued!
Lets say I have 2 shifts in a power plant, shift 1 = 10pm - 4am and shift 2 = 8am - 4pm. Between 4am and 8am there is no work going on at the plant. Cell A1 = Inbound Time, Cell B1 = Outbound Time and Cell C1 = Processing (or work) Time. I am trying to find a formula which can calculate the processing time, say for example inbound time (in cell A2) is 6:00am and Outbound time (in cell B2) is 15:00 then my processing time in cell C2 should be 6.

```
IF((IF 4:00<A2<8:00,"0", ??)
```

The time syntax totally confuses me. I was thinking about an Nested IF statement where there are 4 cases, 1) Inbound and outbound times fall in between both shift ranges, 2) Outbound is not in range but inbound is, 3) Vice versa of 2, 4) Both times are not in range

Similarly what about writing a macro? (the values of time will probably be always at the hour, eg 2:00, 3:00, 4:00 and in 24 hour clock format). I defined the variables and I think a method to show clock hours for inbound and outbound but I am stuck

```
sub time() 
dim inbound as string 
dim outbound as string 
dim processing as string 
inbound = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Value 
outbound = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Value 
processing = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").Value 
IF Len(inbound) = 2 Then 
   inbound = "00:" & inbound 
ELSEIF Len(inbound) = 3 Then 
   inbound = "0" & Left(inbound,1) & ":" & Right(inbound,2) 
ELSEIF Len(inbound) = 4 Then inbound = Left(val,2) & ":" & Right  (inbound,2)  
ELSE inbound = "Not a valid time"
```

(same if else statements afterwards for outbound also)

Please your assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1391557/edit) to give us sample data?

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your explanation. What are “inbound time” and “outbound time”, and how does “processing time” relate to them and the shift schedule? A quick glance at your code tells me that it doesn’t even try to do anything related to *solving* the problem. (In  this context, I don’t consider validation, preparation and pre-processing of the input to be a step in solving the problem.) It might help if you showed us one or two (or three or four) examples of each of your four cases.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  It would probably help if you picked one time format and used it consistently.  I suggest 24-hour time; so shift 1 is 2200-0400, etc.  I suggest multiple examples for each of your four cases because, in addition to your tests, we need to see examples of times before midnight and after midnight.  And explain!  How do you get 6:00 → 15:00 = 6 hours? P.S. Are your shifts really different lengths?

Answer (score 0):

This formula covers jobs coming in after the end of work yesterday and completed today.  Also 15:00-8:00 = 7 hours, not 6.  Is there a lunch hour?

```
=(IF(VALUE(A1)>VALUE("16:00"),VALUE("24:00")-IF(VALUE(A1)<VALUE("22:00"),VALUE("22:00"),VALUE(A1)),0)+IF(VALUE(B1)>VALUE("16:00"),VALUE("16:00"),VALUE(B1))-IF(VALUE(A1)<VALUE("8:00"),VALUE("8:00"),VALUE(A1))+IF(VALUE(A1)<VALUE("4:00"),VALUE("4:00")-VALUE(A1),0))*24
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to have a couple of calculation cells.

Make `E2` the low side overlap of `A2` with the downtime: `=MIN(MAX(A2,"4:00"),"8:00")`

Make `F2` the low side overlap of `B2` with the downtime: `=MAX(MIN(B2,"8:00"),"4:00")`

Then the calculation in `C2` is straightforward: `=B2-A2-(F2-E2)`

For example:

```
| |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |
|1|  In   |  Out  |  Work |       |  Min  |  Max  |
|2|  6:00 | 10:00 |   2h  |       |  6:00 |  8:00 |
|3|  9:00 | 10:00 |   1h  |       |  8:00 |  8:00 |
|4|  2:00 | 10:00 |   4h  |       |  4:00 |  8:00 |
```